# How to add space between the Flex items in ReactJs?

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

[This is the image of the code and the page.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Vx1jr.png)

The justifyconent attribute in the Containerr doesn't seem to work. Why are the 3 children elements stuck together with no space?

EDIT: I tried `justifyContent` too. (instead of `JustifyContent` as in the picture..)

Answer (score 3):

Keys for styles in ReactJs should be lower camel case.
In your case, you are using JustifyContent. Instead, it should justifyContent.

```
justifyContent : 'space-between'
```

This should solve your problem.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like the `<Paper/>` components are simply filling the available space. I tried to make a SUPER simple CodePen to demonstrate this (https://codepen.io/venetian13/pen/xPvYaM). `flex: 1` and `flex 4` will fill available space in proportion to each other `| 1 |    4    | 1 |`. If you want them to be separate you have to give them a cumulative width > the containers total width.

Great Reference : https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/

Comment: Does the syntax change in javascript for reactjs?

Comment: Also, What if I needed a 4th component below 1st?

Comment: I assume when you ask, "Does the syntax change in javascript for reactjs?" you are reffering to the styling (css). If you inline style in React you have to use lowerCamelCase just as @Amogh P mentioned in his answer. Let me know if you want me to convert the css for you.

Comment: If you need a 4th component below the first one, I would just likely wrap it in a different div. Ultimately there are a lot of ways and I would need to see/know what you are aiming for to advise you on the best route.

Answer (score 1):

Your style must be in lower camel case like

```html
<div style={{ display:"flex", flexWrap:"wrap", justifyContent:"space-between"}}>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the margin attributes to add some spacing to the `Paper` component. It's responsive as well.

```
const styles = {
  root: {
    flexGrow: 1
  },
  paper: {
    padding: 5,
    textAlign: "center",
    marginRight: 4,
    marginTop: 10
  }
};
```

It should work for any other component that fits this case as well. (Ex: Card)